# How to iterate the knockout form element passed on submit

Tags: javascript, forms, dom, knockout.js

I have a form which I would like to submit in the normal way with Knockout, bind it to a function and rather than access the elements like

```
 var value = form.element
```

I want to iterate through the form elements.  The form object doesn't seem to contain the elements until they are accessed, so how can they be iterated without knowing the id's of them? I would like to avoid numeric ids and a for loop.
Here is what I have which does not work:

```
 saveChanges: function(form) {
        form.each(function( element ) {
            //do something 
        });
```

the output of `console.log()` for the form object is something weird like:

```
 {"0":{},"1":{"__ko__1429589442426":"ko66"},     
 "2":{"__ko__1429589442426":"ko74"},
 "3":{"__ko__1429589442426":"ko79"},
 "4":{},"__ko__1429589442426":"ko60"}
```

Any suggestions?

Edit: why do I need to do this?

My form elements come from my api, which is a made with a strongly typed language.  The 'preferences' each have values for 'booleanvalue', 'numericvalue', 'stringvalue', and a preferred type, either 'bool', 'numb', or 'stri'.  On calling the api, I get back all the values, then show only the preferred one using knockout's if: binding.

example of return from api:

```
[{"type":"bool","stringvalue":null,"preference":"taxable","numericvalue":"0","id":3,"booleanvalue":true},{"type":"stri","stringvalue":"Acme inc.","preference":"company_name","numericvalue":"0","id":2,"booleanvalue":false}]
```

When I collect the form input onsubmit, I need to get the name of the preference and the column name, the booleanvalue, stringvalue, numericvalue.  I did this by setting the id attribute to contain the information, so that I could parse the id key to get the column names, and use the value as the column value. Here is an example:

```
id= company_name.stringvalue value= "acme co."

id= taxable.booleanvalue value= "true"

id= tax_rate.numericvalue value= "0.0112"
```

This is inside of a Durandal app, so the fiddle does not work, but you can see my html/js.  https://jsfiddle.net/ggja7qv2/

The reason I did not hard code these is because I will add more preferences in the future from the api, and I want the front end to be able to edit those without having to go back into it and change things.  The front end should sent JSON to the api in the form

```
{"data":[{"preference":"company_name","stringvalue":"acme inc"},{"preference":"taxable","booleanvalue":"false"}]}
```

Comment: can you please make a fiddle showing your html and form variable

Comment: **Don't go down this path!** At least not while also using KnockoutJS. Perhaps you're experiencing a case of [the XY-problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)? With KO, you hardly ever need to access DOM elements like that, especially with form input values. I suggest you have a look at [the load/save tutorial](http://learn.knockoutjs.com/#/?tutorial=loadingsaving).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jquery:

```
$(form).find('input')
```

This will give you back all the form elements.

OTOH, please, don't store the info in the id. You can use `data-` attributes, one for each piece of information, and later read them in this way:

```
$(form).find('input')[0].attr('data-booleanvalue')
```

The generated input should look like this:

```
<input type="...." data-booleanvalue="true" ... />
```

Answer (score 1):

This problem is fun to solve with pure knockout :)

First thing you need is a view model that handles your weird multi-type preferences.  Let's call it `Preference`:

```
// dictionary to convert preference types to 
// the properties that hold their values
var typeToValueName = {
    bool: 'booleanvalue',
    stri: 'stringvalue',
    nume: 'numericvalue',
};
// dictionary from types to valid html input types
var typeToInputType = {
    bool: 'checkbox',
    stri: 'text',
    nume: 'number',
};

function Preference(data) {
    this.preference = data.preference;
    this.valueTypeName = typeToValueName[data.type];
    this.inputType = typeToInputType[data.type];
    this.value = ko.observable(data[this.valueTypeName]);
    // if this is a checkbox, the value is bound differently (you can make this computed if you're dynamically changing your input types)
    this.isCheckbox = this.inputType === 'checkbox';
}
```

Then you need to bind an array of these to your form:

```
<form data-bind="submit: save">
    <!-- ko ifnot: preferences().length -->
    Loading preferences...
    <!-- /ko -->
    <!-- ko foreach: preferences -->
    <label>
        <span data-bind="text: preference"></span>
        <!-- ko if: isCheckbox -->
        <input data-bind="attr: {type: inputType}, checked: value"/>
        <!-- /ko -->
        <!-- ko ifnot: isCheckbox -->
        <input data-bind="attr: {type: inputType}, value: value"/>
        <!-- /ko -->
    </label>
    <br/>
    <!-- /ko -->
    <input type="submit" value="Save"></input>
</form>
```

And finally you need to map this array to a simpler array when you submit your form:

```
var vm = {
    preferences: ko.observable([]), // no need to make this an observable array unless you're dealing with adding/removing preferences one by one.

    save: function () {
        console.log(this.preferences().map(function(p){
            var outputFormat = { preference: p.preference };
            outputFormat[p.valueTypeName] = p.value();
            return outputFormat;
        }));
    }
};
```

You can automate a lot of the above, but this is spelled out so it can help you start thinking about "the knockout way".  Good luck, and here's a fiddle of all that to play with: http://jsfiddle.net/h2qq0k42/